python on xampp how to serve html page
xampp running a python script that writes an html file. How do i get xampp to serve the html from python.
name = "david"
age = 44
square = age**0.5
HTML=f"""
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Download</title>
</head>
<body>
    {name} age is {age} but he is square so age is{square}
</body>
</html>
"""
with open("test.html","w") as new_file:
    new_file.write(HTML)

This writes test.html how do i ask xampp to display

it is not clear what you're trying to achieve. the point of dynamic content is to avoid writing it to the drive

After generating the document test.html (typically located at C:\xampp\htdocs\test.html or where your xampp is installed), simply try to access it using the address http://localhost/test.html
Edit: Added following code
Can you try this now:
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import cgi

name = "david"
age = 44
square = age**0.5
HTML=f"""
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Dynamic Output</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>{name} age is {age} but he is square so age is {square}</p>
</body>
</html>
"""

# for output
print("Content-Type: text/html\n")
print(HTML)


The answer is not answering the question. Its how do I get the test.html to be served by xampp  immediately upon the write of the html to display in localhost with no intervention from the user.

XAMPP serves files from the htdocs folder by default

or you may want to open that via a web browser after running the script?

BTW, did you change your document's path (with open("test.html","w") in your code) to the correct one as I described?

xampp is already running so that wont work, trying to display resulting html without typing localhost ie restarting the browser session. so i need some code to do that. Quote--"xampp to serve the html from python".

xampp already running the python file via cgi

if that python is already running, it should display the stdout data, try the code added above

changed a bit as using linux the #! line and removed the import cgi code above works fine will try to progress further thanks
